# chrome.notification.create not displaying notification on OS X

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

I have developed an extension and using Chrome API, which sends notification every 20 secs from background script

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "register.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": ["idle", "tabs", "gcm", "storage", "notifications"],
  "icons": { "128": "gcm_128.png" }
}
```

background.js //sends notification

```
  function messageReceived(message) {
    var messageString = '';
    if(message) messageString = message;
    var nid = getNotificationId();
    messageString = messageString + nid;

    // Pop up a notification to show the GCM message.
    chrome.notifications.create(nid, {
      title: 'Kukdu Kuuu',
      iconUrl: 'gcm_128.png',
      type: 'basic',
      message: messageString
    }, function() {});
  }

  // Returns a new notification ID used in the notification.
  function getNotificationId() {
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9007199254740992) + 1;
    return id.toString();
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    console.log('running - ');
    messageReceived('test notification ');
  }, 20000);
```

It shows a notification when I am not on Chrome browser i.e when I am out of focus. But I don't receive notification when I am working on chrome.

When I run API, `chrome.notifications.getAll()`, I get the entire queue of IDs.

But, notifications are not getting displayed immediately on my system. What could be the problem? However, it works well on the windows machine.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. See if it's reported on https://crbug.com or submit a new report.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: osx extensions in chrome now use the os notification manager. likely they are in some notification drawer.

Comment: @wOxxOm This is a bug in chrome. Here is the link. This is sort of intentional behavior. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=583746#

Answer (score 1):

This is an open issue in chrome.

Here is the link,

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=583746#

Important comments & summary,

> This is definitely intentional but is is also a questionable decision.
>
> Pro: * Won't interrupt immersive content such as movies with a
> notification.
>
> Con: * People use full screen to just browse as well,
> esp. on Mac with the new fullscreen mode.
>
> ( Comment by dewittj@chromium.org )

And current behaviour of pushnotifications,

> It queues received notification while in full-screen mode.
>
> It shows all the notifications when user exits fullscreen mode or switch to some other app or window.
>
> If the user exits the browser, the notifications is displayed on next browser restart.